# Assigning an integer variable a value from dynamic SOQL query

Tags: apex, soql

I was hoping I can get some help.

So I have a wrapper where populating an integer variable inside a for-loop, with a SQL COUNT() query works well.  example:

```
eachwrap.numOpsPM = [SELECT Count() from operational_projects__c where Project_Manager_Lookup__c =:StringID ];
```

Now, I want to add filters dynamically, so I change it to what's below.  It doesn't work, since the result is a list.

```
soqlpm = 'SELECT Count() from operational_projects__c where Project_Manager_Lookup__c =:StringID '    
eachwrap.numOpsPM = database.query(SoqlPM)
```

I've tried making a temporary list variable to hold the list value, and then convert it back to integer.

```
varOpstemp= database.query(soqlPM) ;
if (varOpsTemp.size() >0 ){
           eachwrap.numOpsPM = integer.valueof(varOpsTemp[0]);
}
```

This doesn't work, but instead gives me a "use countQuery() for [select count()...] queries"  Error, in my exception capture.

Obviously I'm going about this the wrong way.  I couldn't find anything on countQuery() at ALL.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the `Database.countQuery` [method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_countQuery).

```
eachwrap.numOpsPM = database.countQuery(SoqlPM);
```

Comment: YOU'RE AMAZING!  Thank you, I've been at this for the last hour.  That makes so much sense.  I was looking for that method EVERYWHERE... except in database...   Thanks man!!

Comment: Ha. Just heard of it recently myself. Glad this helped.